# QGIS 3.6 Noosa on Windows 10 cannot start

Tags: qgis, installation

Recently downloaded QGIS 3.6 and I cannot open it from the desktop shortcut. It doesn't work when I run as an administrator either. The only way I am able to open the program is if I go to open an existing QGIS file saved on my old version of QGIS (2.18 Las Palmas).

Is there a setting that is making this happen?

Comment: try running C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\bin\qgis-bin.exe

Comment: @Mapperz strangely I don't have a folder like that in ProgramFiles. There is a QGIS3.4 which only has 8 CMAKE files inside it.

Comment: search for qgis-bin.exe on your local drive (I don't know your setup and everyone is different)

Comment: @Mapperz I was able to find the `qgis-bin.exe` under the OSGeo folder but running it from there made no difference. I also noticed there is a `qgis-bin-g7.exe` file inside that same folder. Would my environment variables have anything to do with the issue?

Comment: I would re-install qgis 3.6.

Comment: I would also suggest that first uninstall all previous versions of QGIS 3. Try installing from the standalone installer and if that doesnt work, try the other installer.